# How to add an "exception" or "condition" in this code (javascript, jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an exception or condition in this code.

```
var a = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on("change", "#txtInput" ,function(){
            $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>"+$("#txtInput").val()+"</td></tr>");
                a += 1;
                var str = 'Total Bianuales: '
                $('p').html(str + a);
              }
           )

    });
```

This is how it works: I get a value with the ID `txtInput`. I got some condition about this ID up in my code but I want to apply it when it add the value in a table that it's created. How do I make a condition that only append the value I get from `txtInput` when it's major or equal than 9?

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: You can use an `if` condition to validate it

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that *change* fires when **input** looses focus so you will need to click out of the control to cause it to fire.  If you wanted it to fire on each keystroke then you want the *input* event.

```js
var a = 0;
$(document).on("change", "#txtInput",function(){
  var inputLength = this.value.length;
  if (inputLength <= 8) { return; }

  $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>" + this.value + "</td></tr>");
  $("p").html('Total Bianuales: ' + (++a));
});
```

```html
<input id="txtInput" />
<table id="contenido"></table>
<p></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting "NaN" when I run this. I would like to add in the table the value I type on "input". For example, if I type "DR0010001" (ID that we use at work), I want it to be add in the table. But if I type any value lower than 9 characters, I don't want it to be add in the table. Because with the code I show you early, it does it.

Comment: I thought you wanted to ensure that the "value" of the input was more than 8.  Now that I know you want the length of the string to be more than 8, I have updated the code.

Comment: Now it's working as expected. Thank you so much @JonSG!

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "#txtInput" ,function(){
    var textinput = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (textinput > 8) {
      $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>"+$(this).val()+"</td></tr>");
      a += 1;
      var str = 'Total Bianuales: '
      $('p').html(str + a);
    }}
  );
});
```

Comment: You might simplify with **var textinput = parseInt(this.value);** and once you have **textinput**, you can use it again when building the table row.